# How to create a SpringBoot app according to rest services?

Tags: spring-boot

I want to implement REST Services through SpringBoot to create a front End Web API, I want to get an example of Spring Application??

I have implemnted the models for a Comment class and here is my code.........

package Spring.Spring.model;

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection="collection")
public class Comment {
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
    private String Id;
    private String message;

    public String getID(){
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(String id){
        Id=id;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

And to connect to the backend i have application properties file like this

```
server.port=8881
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.post=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=comments
```

Comment: refer this for start: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the services according to your model

```
package SpringBootWithMongo.SpringBootWithMongo.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import SpringBootWithMongo.SpringBootWithMongo.model.User;
import SpringBootWithMongo.SpringBootWithMongo.model.UserRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class UserService {
        @Autowired
        private UserRepository repository;

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public void AddUser(@RequestBody User instance) {
            try {
                repository.save(instance);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("finally")
        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public List<User> GetAllUsers() {
            List<User> userList = null;
            try {
                userList = repository.findAll();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                return userList;
            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("finally")
        @RequestMapping(value = "/{Id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public User getSingle(@PathVariable String Id) {
            User instance = null;
            try {
                instance = this.findOne(Id);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                return instance;
            }
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/{Id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
        public void updateUser(@RequestBody User instance, @PathVariable String Id) {
            try {
                User updateInstance = this.findOne(Id);
                updateInstance.setName(instance.getName());
                repository.save(updateInstance);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/{Id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
        public void deleteUser(@PathVariable String Id) {
            try {
                repository.delete(this.findOne(Id));
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("finally")
        private User findOne(String Id) {
            User instance = null;
            try {
                List<User> userList = repository.findAll();
                for(User user: userList) {
                    if(user.getId().equals(Id)) {
                        instance =  user;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                return instance;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: server.port=8881
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.post=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=comments

Answer (score 0):

And please refer this code for the repository

```
package SpringBootWithMongo.SpringBootWithMongo.model;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String>{

}
```

Comment: You have 3 separate Answers to this question. Unless you are answering with 3 completely separate ways of performing this task, then you shouldn't have 3 totally separate answers. There is an [edit] button below each answer, which you should use to add additional information to an already existing answer. If these are all one set of code, which is all needed to actually answer, then please edit your oldest answer to consolidate these into one Answer and delete the others. Currently, they are likely to get down-votes, just due to having 3 Answers on the same question (which is *very* unusual).